# Custom Error pages in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config, asp.net-mvc-5

I have been trying to configure Custom Error pages in ASP.NET MVC 5 but with little complete success.

To do this, I have followed this guide: http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-mvc-custom-error-pages

Web.config `customerrors`

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/500.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
  <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/401.aspx" />
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/401.aspx" />
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.aspx" />      
</customErrors>
```

Web.config `httpErrors`

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" >
  <remove statusCode="401" />
  <error statusCode="401" path="401.html" responseMode="File" />
  <remove statusCode="403" />
  <error statusCode="403" path="401.html" responseMode="File" />
  <remove statusCode="404" />
  <error statusCode="404" path="404.html" responseMode="File"/>
  <remove statusCode="500" />
  <error statusCode="500" path="500.html" responseMode="File" />
</httpErrors>
```

I have removed the `HandleErrorAttribute` from filter config.

With this setup, I get the following results:

- **Browse to a non-existent static resource**
  Example: http://my.website.com/fakeresource.htm
  This results in the static 404.htm file configured in the httpErrors section.
  The Url is preserved in the browser address bar
  A 404 status code is correctly set.
- **Browse to a bad route**
  Example: http://my.website/realcontroller/fakeaction
  This results in a `HttpException` being thrown when a matching route cannot be found.
  The 404.aspx page is displayed.
  The Url is preserved in the browser address bar.
  A 404 status code is correctly set.
- **Browse to a valid route, but with an invalid ID for a database resource**
  Example: http://my.website.com/realcontroller/realaction/22
  (22 is the ID of a resource which does not exist, the Action will return the `HttpNotFound()` method.  
  This results in the static 404.htm file configured in the httpErrors section.
  The Url is preserved in the browser address bar
  A 404 status code is correctly set.
  If I throw `HttpException(404, "Not Found")` instead of using `HttpNotFound()`, I get the 404 defined in `customErrors`
- **Exceptions & Unauthorised Requests**
  Also all work correctly using this configuration of Web.config

However, any action which checks ModelState with `ModelSate.IsValid`, or adds errors using `ModelState.AddModelError("InputName", "Error Message");` results in a 400 Bad request.

Here are the errors I get in IE & Chrome:

**IE**
[image: IE]

**Chrome**
[image: Chrome]

Instead, what I should be getting is the original view, with the validation messages displayed next to the inputs which failed validation.

If I remove the `httpErrors` section from web.config, the issue is resolved, but I no longer get custom IIS error pages.

I have also tried every option of the `existingResponse` property on `httpErrors` but different options breaks either the error pages or the `ModelState` validation.

Finally I tried setting `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;` and this appear to fix the problem in the action I was testing.

But this means that I have to set this property on every action which uses `ModelState`, and that just doesn't sound right.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
To test if this was project specific, I created a new project in VS2012 and configured the same error pages. Frustratingly, everything worked.  The only difference I can think of now is that the project experiencing the problem originally started out using MVC 4, and was upgraded to MVC 5.

Comment: Have you tried setting detailed errors to on in IIS? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2007/05/25/iis7-how-to-enable-the-detailed-error-messages-for-the-website-while-browsed-from-for-the-client-browsers.aspx

Comment: @Slicksim My understanding is that this is exactly what the `httpErrors` section is configuring in web.config

Comment: I thought the same, but practice shows something different.  With the responsecode being set to an error, IIS 7+ hides the html that is returned and injects it's own.  setting the detailed errors to on fixed loads of issues i had with things like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that custom errors had nothing to do with the bad request I encountered.
Instead, there was another form on the page which was incorrectly also being called when the main form was being posted.