# Custom Error Pages In MVC Are Not Being Served

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, custom-error-pages

I am trying to setup custom error pages in my ASP.NET MVC (version 5.2.3)project.  I followed [prescribed setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852736/custom-error-pages-in-mvc-5), but I still cannot get the pages to show up.

I have tried to test the pages by raising an exception in one of my controller actions.

So, my questions are...

1. How do I setup custom pages?
2. How do I setup tests for them?

Can anyone help guide me please?

**MY WEB.CONFIG LOOKS LIKE:**

```
<system.web>  

    <!-- CUSTOM ERRORS: customErrors -->
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/views/errors/error.cshtml" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
      <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/views/errors/forbidden.cshtml" />
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/views/errors/forbidden.cshtml" />
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/views/errors/notfound.cshtml" />
    </customErrors>

  </system.web>
<system.webServer>

    <!-- CUSTOM ERRORS: httpErrors -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="Replace" errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="401" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="401" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="~/views/errors/forbidden.cshtml" responseMode="File" />
      <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="403" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="~/views/errors/forbidden.cshtml" responseMode="File" />
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="~/views/errors/notfound.cshtml" responseMode="File" />
      <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="~/views/errors/error.cshtml" responseMode="File" />
    </httpErrors>

  </system.webServer>
```

**MY CONTROLLER ACTION LOOKS LIKE:**
Here is an example of my controller.

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    #region <Actions>

    // GET: Home/Index
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        TraceHandler.TraceIn(TraceLevel.Info);
        var unitOfWork = new AmericaVirtualToursUnitOfWork();
        var viewmodel = new HomeIndexViewModel(unitOfWork, User);

        // Trying to get the ERROR page to show
        throw new ApplicationException("Testing");

        TraceHandler.TraceOut();
        return View(viewmodel);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**The path to the CSHTML files is correct...**
[image]

**When responseMode="File"...**
This is what I get...
[image]

Comment: You should not be serving cshtml files directly from customErrors.

Comment: @ErikPhilips  Okay...that's cool.  Why?  And...what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I accomplish something similar, creating an Error Controller, with 3 different methods(`Error401,Error403,Error404`), with the following `web.config` pointing to the controller:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
  <error redirect="~/Error/Error401" statusCode="401" />
  <error redirect="~/Error/Error403" statusCode="403" />    
  <error redirect="~/Error/Error404" statusCode="404" />
</customErrors>
```